# how to write superscript in pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have to edit 1<sup>st</sup> in pdf but i don't know how to do can anyone please help me out

For example;

Like this

1<sup>st</sup>

Is there any shortcut for the superscript in pdf. please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which tool you use for creating PDF files, but since you are asking about PDF in general and not a specific tool, I checked with the PDF spec (I have a copy of the ISO standard), and found two points superscripts are mentioned:

PDF has a "Text raise" command (`Ts`), which can be used to make a superscript, but it doesn't change font size, so that should be done manually.

There is also a `BaselineShift` property for texts that can be used for the same effect.

So, in any tool you are using, you could increase baseline shift and reduce font size to make superscript.

Comment: Can you give a link to this PDF spec?  I can't find documentation anywhere.  Thanks

Comment: The actual ISO standard (like other ISO standard documentations) is available for purchase from ISO. Fortunately, Adobe are providing [this PDF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for free. It's not the PDF standard, but has the same technical content.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'edit text and images' under the  'content editing'. Choose the desired font which includes a superscript too.

Answer (score -1):

I just use this function like the last answer it does not change the font size but give the th,nd ie...

```
Public function SupScript(d)
    Select Case d
    Case 1,21,31:strSup = "st"
    Case 2,22:strSup = "nd"
    Case 3,23:strSup = "rd"
    Case Else:strSup = "th"
    End Select
SupScript = strSup

End Function
```

daynumber & SupScript(daynumber)